# Is the commandment not to dwell in Egypt or not to dwell among Egyptians?

Tags: mitzvah, egypt

The Semag, in his [Sefer Mitzvot Gadol, Negative Command 227](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Mitzvot_Gadol%2C_Negative_Commandments.227?lang=bi), seems to say that the commandment not to dwell in Egypt permanently does not apply anymore because today's Egyptians are not the descendants of those who lived in Pharaoh’s day, as most Egyptians were exiled by Sennacherib and the Assyrians, mixed with other populations, and could not be distinguished from them.

But the ban refers to “Egypt”, not to “the Egyptians”.  What is the resolution?

Comment: Well, if you say [the reason for the prohibition was not to learn from their ways](https://thetaryag.com/chinuch/500), and halacha is determined by the reason behind the mitzvah, then maybe it's not so unusual. Although, we usually say אין דורשין טעמא דקרא

Comment: @robev Sounds worthy of being an answer to me

Comment: @Jay it would be if I could prove the Semag holds דורשין טעמא דקרא, as that he agrees with the Chinuch. Neither is necessarily true

Answer (score -2):

the Rambam who recently lived in Egypt about 700+ years ago writes that he transgresses 3 commandments per day living in Egypt. At that time the Egyptians originally from the times of the exodus were no longer there, as sancheyriv scattered them (see sotah beginning, I believe around page 8 or 9). He additionally codified the various other laws specifying the parameters of living in Egypt, hilchos melachim ch. 5

7
It is permitted to dwell anywhere in the entire world with the exception of the land of Egypt. Its territory includes a square of 400 parsah by 400 parsah from the Mediterranean Sea proceeding westward, bordering on the land of Kush and the desert. It is forbidden to dwell in this entire territory.

In three places, the Torah warned against returning to Egypt:

a) 'God has told you, you must never again return on that path' (Deuteronomy 17:16);

b) 'You shall not see it again' (Deuteronomy 28:68);

c) 'You shall never see them again forever' (Exodus 14:13).

Alexandria is included in this prohibition.

ז
וּמֻתָּר לִשְׁכֹּן בְּכָל הָעוֹלָם חוּץ מֵאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם. מִן הַיָּם הַגָּדוֹל וְעַד הַמַּעֲרָב אַרְבַּע מֵאוֹת פַּרְסָה עַל אַרְבַּע מֵאוֹת פַּרְסָה כְּנֶגֶד אֶרֶץ כּוּשׁ וּכְנֶגֶד הַמִּדְבָּר. הַכּל אָסוּר לְהִתְיַשֵּׁב בָּהּ. בִּשְׁלֹשָׁה מְקוֹמוֹת הִזְהִירָה תּוֹרָה שֶׁלֹּא לָשׁוּב לְמִצְרַיִם. שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים יז טז) "לֹא תֹסִפוּן לָשׁוּב בַּדֶּרֶךְ הַזֶּה עוֹד". (דברים כח סח) "לֹא תֹסִיף עוֹד לִרְאֹתָהּ". (שמות יד יג) "לֹא תֹסִפוּ לִרְאֹתָם עוֹד עַד עוֹלָם". וַאֲלֶכְּסַנְדְּרִיאָה בִּכְלַל הָאִסּוּר:

8
It is permitted to return to Egypt for the purpose of trade and commerce and to pass through while conquering other nations. The prohibition consists of settling there.

Lashes are not given as punishment for the violation of this prohibition because at the time one enters, there is no prohibition. Should he decide to settle there, there is no deed involved.

It appears to me that if a king of Israel would conquer the land of Egypt with the approval of the court, it would be permissible to settle there. The prohibition against returning was only given to individuals or to dwell there while it is under the rule of the gentiles for their behavior is more depraved than that of the peoples of other lands as can be inferred from Leviticus 18:3: 'Do not follow the ways of Egypt....'

ח
מֻתָּר לַחְזֹר לְאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם לִסְחוֹרָה וְלִפְרַקְמַטְיָא. וְלִכְבֹּשׁ אֲרָצוֹת אֲחֵרוֹת. וְאֵין אָסוּר אֶלָּא לְהִשְׁתַּקֵעַ שָׁם. וְאֵין לוֹקִין עַל לָאו זֶה. שֶׁבְּעֵת הַכְּנִיסָה מֻתָּר הוּא. וְאִם יַחֲשֹׁב לֵישֵׁב וּלְהִשְׁתַּקֵעַ שָׁם אֵין בּוֹ מַעֲשֶׂה. וְיֵרָאֶה לִי שֶׁאִם כָּבַשׁ אֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם מֶלֶךְ יִשְׂרָאֵל עַל פִּי בֵּית דִּין שֶׁהִיא מֻתֶּרֶת. וְלֹא הִזְהִירָה אֶלָּא לָשׁוּב לָהּ יְחִידִים אוֹ לִשְׁכֹּן בָּהּ וְהִיא בְּיַד עַכּוּ''ם מִפְּנֵי שֶׁמַּעֲשֶׂיהָ מְקֻלְקָלִין יוֹתֵר מִכָּל הָאֲרָצוֹת. שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ויקרא יח ג) "כְּמַעֲשֵׂה אֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם":

---

See also https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/976660/jewish/The-Prohibition-Against-Living-in-Egypt.htm#footnoteRef17a976660

Also the smag quoted doesn't conclude with that reason, that was only an introduction of a possibility, but he rejects it at the end of that piece, instead concluding that only from eretz Yisroel to Egypt is forbidden, but not from other lands

ואומר שם למצרים נתן להם הכתוב קצבה שנא' מקץ ארבעים שנה אקבץ מצרים מן העמים אשר נפוצו שם וישובו על אדמתם, וגם בסוכה אומר ואלכסנדריא מ"ט דאיענוש משום דעברו אהאי קרא דלא תוסיפו לשוב וגו' ואותו מעשה היה אחר בלבול של סנחריב ואין (ג) טעם להתיר אם לא נפרש כפירוש הרב ר"א ממיץ לא תוסיפו וגו' לא אסרה תורה אלא בדרך הזה כלו' מארץ ישראל למצרים אבל משאר ארצות מותר:

Comment: Can you source your first sentence? Most of this answer seems irrelevant to the question and is distracting. Your final point about the smag rejecting this position doesn't really answer the question because he's just disputing the fact that sancherev removed the Egyptians, not that had he done so it would become permitted.

Comment: @DoubleAA -- The Rambam’s grandson said that the Rambam signed some letters “Moshe ben Maimon, who violates the commandment not to dwell in Egypt every day”. [reported by Rabbi Ishtori Haparchi (1280-1366), in Kaftor v'Ferah, ch. 5] But no such letters have survived.

Comment: @maurice it's in the mishneh Torah itself

Comment: Where exactly?---

Comment: @maurice trying to find it now thought I recalled reading it there..